# receiving and displaying html data via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, google-maps

**** UPDATE ****

I have the AJAX working (See below) but now the modal overlay won't close after it's been opened. Any thoughts why? (see the jsfiddle on the original post for the overlay JS)

```
  map.addMarker({
  lat: 34.5333,
  lng: 69.1333,
  title: 'Afghanistan',
  click: function(){
    if ($('#modal-shade').length == 0)
    var a = $(this).attr('title');
    var jqhxr = $.ajax( 'inc/parser.php?country='+a )
        .done(function(data) {  
            $('.modal').html(data);
            openOverlay('.modal');
            return false;
         });
      }
  });
```

**** ORIGINAL POST ****

I'm using gmaps.js (http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) to show a map with several markers on different countries. I'm trying to get it set up so that when a user clicks on a specific marker, it hits up a PHP script (ie, script.php?country=USA), queries a database to populate a chunk of html with country specific data, and returns that country data to display in a modal (http://jsfiddle.net/istvanv/uQj7t/28/), all via AJAX.

I'm not a javascript guy at all, and I'm not sure how I can go about making this work dynamically, without having the code for each modal individually on the page, making the page size huge. Here's what I'm doing:

```
map.addmarker({
    lat: 0.0000,
    lng: 0.0000,
    title: USA,
    click: function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/parser.php?country=USA',
        type: 'GET',
        data: 'USA',
        });
    openOverlay('.USA').html(data);
    preventDefault();
    }
});

// more map markers here
```

parser.php is just a php/mysql query grabbing the country data based on the passed variable and filling out a template - this part works fine when I hit the page with a country variable:

```
if(isset($_GET['country']) && !empty($_GET['country'])) {
    $country = $_GET['country'];

//connection stuff here

$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE country = '". $country ."' LIMIT 1");

while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
    echo 'Population: '. $row->population .' people
          etc
          etc
          etc';
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
```

I know it's likely hideous and laughable but I've been hacking away at it and it's a complete hatchet job now. Can someone give me hand with that AJAX?

Comment: What is your actual question? What are your errors, did you try debugging everything? Does the AJAX fire? What does the openOverlay function look like?

Answer (score 0):

Could you seperate the add marker ajax request? When you click on the marker, get its title attribute and pass it on to you ajax url.

eg.

```
map.addmarker({
    lat: 0.0000,
    lng: 0.0000,
    title: USA,

});// for each marker

$(".YourMarkersClass")click( function(){
        var a= $(this).attr("title");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/parser.php?country='+a,
            type: 'GET',
            data: a,
            });
        openOverlay('.'+a).html(data);
        preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: I've tried that but I get `TypeError: openOverlay(...) is undefined` in the console.

Comment: Where is this function defined?

Comment: It resides just above the addmarker code on the page and I'm using the code found here for the openOverlay function: http://jsfiddle.net/istvanv/uQj7t/28/ for the modal. Furthermore, it doesn't appear the individual markers have classes assigned.

Comment: Is the second function in the answer above(with YourClassMarker selector) below the openOvelray function?

Comment: Yes it is, but again, there is no individual classes on the markers so targeting them separately like that might not work?

Comment: It should have a class if there is any css attached to the markers. It may only be dynamically generated, so you may have to check VIA your web inspector.

Comment: I've moved it to a temp live setup if that helps. Lots of moving parts: http://www.littleredcapsule.ca/test - I'm using the Afghanistan marker as the test case.

Comment: Do you need to use the auther attr. for anything?

Comment: Just in the modal window to close it.